# How to insert a star into the Chile flag using Turtle graphics

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle graphics and I was able to create the most of the Chilean flag. Here is my code so far.

```
import turtle


def rectangle(wdth, ht, c):
  turtle.fillcolor(c)
  turtle.begin_fill()
  for i in range(2):
    turtle.forward(ht)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(wdth)
    turtle.left(90)
   turtle.end_fill()


rectangle(50, 250, "red")

turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)

rectangle(50, 100, "blue")
turtle.right(360)
turtle.forward(50)

rectangle(50, 200, "white")

turtle.done()
```

I want a white star to be placed within the blue box and I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: first create function which draws star. Next you will try to put it in correct place.

Comment: 'star = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(360, 50):
    star.forward()
    star.right()' I'm placing this above the rectangle(50, 200, "white") basically?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is that you lookup the Flag of Chile in Wikipedia and correct your aspect ratio.

Drawing a star is trivial using turtle's `.circle()` function:

```
import turtle

STAR_SIZE = 27

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(-STAR_SIZE, 720, 5)  # twice around the circle in five steps
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.done()
```

But there are complications if/when we want to make it a *filled* star.  On Windows implementations of tkinter, the filled star should look fine.  But on Unix-based implementations, you get this:

[image]

In order to get a proper star in both environments, we have to draw it a different way.  I suggest you search SO for tag [turtle-graphics] and term 'star' to see possible solutions.  Here's my personal approach which is to use *stamping*, instead of *drawing*, to make both the star and the flag itself:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

WIDTH = 250
HEIGHT = WIDTH * 2 / 3
STAR = HEIGHT / 8
EXPAND = 1.2
TRANSLATION = STAR * EXPAND / 4
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

tortoise = Turtle('square', visible=False)
tortoise.penup()

tortoise.shapesize(HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE)
tortoise.fillcolor('red')
tortoise.stamp()

tortoise.shapesize(HEIGHT / 2 / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE)
tortoise.sety(tortoise.ycor() + HEIGHT / 4)
tortoise.fillcolor('white')
tortoise.stamp()

tortoise.shapesize(stretch_len=HEIGHT/ 2 / CURSOR_SIZE)
tortoise.backward(HEIGHT / 2)
tortoise.fillcolor('blue')
tortoise.stamp()

# Draw the white star in the blue field

tortoise.shape('triangle')
tortoise.shapesize(STAR * EXPAND / 2 / CURSOR_SIZE, STAR * EXPAND / CURSOR_SIZE)
tortoise.left(18)  # make sure star has an upward point
tortoise.color('white')

for _ in range(5):
    tortoise.right(72)
    tortoise.forward(TRANSLATION)
    tortoise.stamp()
    tortoise.backward(TRANSLATION)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Of course, you can mix and match drawing with stamping.